# Why did my number of shares of stock decrease?

Tags: stocks

I bought 24242 shares for $0.16 each in Dec 2015. Today I logged into my brokerage account and saw that the share price has gone down to $.055 and I now only own 1358 shares.

To my understanding, even though the stock price went down I should still own my 24242 shares, right?  Or is it the case that if a company's stock price goes down stockholders lose shares in the company?

Comment: What company?  There was probably a big reverse split.

Comment: Its ASTI. They did have a reverse split but i wasn't exactly sure what that was or how it affected my shares. So does that mean my shares are gone?

Comment: http://www.streetinsider.com/Corporate+News/Ascent+Solar+Technologies+(ASTI)+Announces+1-for-20+Reverse+Split/11697911.html is a link to the story of the reverse split.

Comment: @Manny: In essence what it means is that they swapped your shares for a smaller number of more valuable shares (but those "more valuable" shares may have decreased in value afterwards).

Answer (score 6):

During a stock split the only thing that changes is the number of shares outstanding.  Typically a stock splits to lower its price per share.  Sometimes if a company's value is falling it will do a reverse split where X shares will be exchanged for Y shares.  This is typically done to avoid being de-listed from an exchange if the price per share falls below a certain threshold, usually $1.  Again the only thing changing is the number of shares outstanding.  A 1 for 20 reverse split means for every 20 shares outstanding the shareholder will be granted one new share.

Example X Co. has 1,000,000 shares outstanding for a price of $100 per share.  It does a 10 for 1 split.  Now there are 10,000,000 shares outstanding for a price of $10 per share.

Example Y Co has 1,000,000 shares outstanding for a price of $1 per share.  It does a 1 for 10 reverse split.  Now there are 100,000 shares outstanding for a price of $10.

Quickly looking at the news for ASTI it looks like it underwent a 1 for 20 reverse split.  You should probably look at your statements and ask your broker how the arithmetic worked in your case.

Investopedia links for [Reverse Stock Split](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/r/reversesplit.asp) and [Stock Split](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/s/stocksplit.asp)

Comment: Thank you very much for the information, it helps explain a lot. Unfortunately i dont have a broker so i'm going to have to do some more research to fully understand exactly how everything went down. Appreciate the help..

Comment: How did you buy the stock?

Comment: Where do you have your brokerage account if not with a broker? Broker can be a company and not necessarily an individual.

Comment: I bought it thru an app called Robinhood

Comment: @Manny then your broker is Robinhood.